# Redundant move in C compiler output

Tags: c, assembly, x86, clang

Following exercise is from [CSAPP](http://csapp.cs.cmu.edu/) 3.21:

```
int loop_while(int a, int b)
{
    int result = 1;
    while (a < b)
    {
        result *= (a+b);
        a++;
    }
    return result;
}
```

gcc generates the following assembly code:

```
  ;a at %ebp+8, b at %ebp+12
    movl 8(%ebp), %ecx
    movl 12(%ebp), %ebx
    movl $1, %eax          ; this one
    cmpl %ebx, %ecx
    jge .L11
    leal (%ebx,%ecx), %edx
    movl $1, %eax          ; and this one
.L12:
    imull %edx, %eax
    addl $1, %ecx
    addl $1, %edx
    cmpl %ecx, %ebx
    jg .L12
.L11: ......
```

I am confused by the `movl $1, %eax` of line 3 and line 7: the `%eax` has not been modified in line 4, 5, 6

```
cmpl %ebx, %ecx
jge .L11
leal (%ebx,%ecx), %edx
```

It would be no need to do the `movl` again.

I try generating assembly code on `x86_64-apple-darwin15.3.0` with `gcc 4.2.1`

```
    movl    $1, %eax
    cmpl    %esi, %edi
    jge LBB0_2
    .align  4, 0x90
LBB0_1:

    leal    (%rsi,%rdi), %ecx
    imull   %ecx, %eax
    incl    %edi
    cmpl    %edi, %esi
    jne LBB0_1
LBB0_2:
    popq    %rbp
    retq
    .cfi_endproc
```

Couldn't find equivalent instructions to the duplicated `movl`.

What's the point in writing the second `movl $1, %eax`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since OS X 10.8, Apple has been symlinking `gcc` to `clang`, so the first code is actually generated by `clang`.

My Clang 3.7.1 also [generates](https://goo.gl/DkJ4js) the same code, even with `-O2` and `-O3`. As you correctly noticed, the second `movl` is pointless.

You might want to [inform](https://llvm.org/bugs/) the LLVM/Clang team about this, if you can reproduce it with the version currently in the [trunk](http://ttp://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/llvm/trunk).